# Filter curl header output in verbose mode

Tags: grep, curl

Using `curl -v ...`, i.e. the verbose mode that prints out the input and output headers. However, this info is not piped and I can not grep-out lines which I dont need.

How can you filter curl header output?

Comment: Previously answered [on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166359/how-to-grep-the-output-of-curl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The header output from `curl` is gets printed to standard error. So you have to use redirection, for example grepping out the `Content-Length` header:

```
curl -v google.com 2>&1 | grep -vi content-length
```

Comment: this does not work as requested, prints all output of the curl command (at least on MacOS)

Comment: @Rocco That is the point of the example, "grepping out" means showing the lines that do not match the pattern, plug in your own grep command for the behavior you want

Comment: @Ferrybig oh, you think "grep-out lines" means getting rid of the lines you are not looking for... seems counter-intuitive to me. I would assume someone is looking for some information like the content-length header and wants to "grep it out" as in "print it out" which would work with your example if you leave out the "v" in the grep.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `curl -v` (verbose mode), a better option is to tell `curl` to output the headers to STDOUT without all of the extra debugging stuff and without printing the response body. This way, you can `grep` through just the response headers, avoid the need for shell redirection, and know that your filtering will not have to understand and parse out `curl`’s internal debugging messages (which are probably not considered part of its API).

You can do this [by combining the `-I` (do not print body), `-X«METHOD»` (override method), and `-s` (silent, do not show progress bars) parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669324/429091).

```
curl -sIXGET https://www.google.com/ | grep -i content-type:
```

- `-s` instructs `curl` to **hide the progress bars**. If omitted and `curl` detects that it is running in a terminal, it will bypass the pipe and directly talk to the terminal to show progress bars which is often unhelpful and clutters up the terminal.
- `-I` instructs `curl` to disconnect from the server after receiving the headers instead of waiting for a body. This is useful if you actually, as stated in your question, are interested in grepping through **only the HTTP response headers**. It also has the side-effect of defaulting the request method to `HEAD` as if you had specified `-XHEAD`.
- `-X«method»` (e.g., `-XGET`) overrides the method. In many cases, a `HEAD` request is what you want because the HTTP standard says that `HEAD` must return the exact same headers as the same `GET` request. However, when debugging a server or working with one which does not adhere to the standard, it can be useful to instruct `curl` to make a `GET` request but disconnect before reading the response body. This way, you can see **the *actual* headers the server would send in response to `GET`** instead of hoping that the server is implemented correctly.

Comment: This is a better answer and should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Comment: why would you add the "-v" option to grep? it outputs all lines NOT matching your query. just `grep -i "access-control-allow-"` to case-insensitive grep all matching headers

Comment: @Rocco I was copying the other answer. I do not know why someone would want everything except for the Content-Length. The question itself doesn’t indicate what the person wants to find. I will make it positive I guess.